# CentOS Samba server 60Kbps download speed over WiFi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, centos, samba

I setup a secure samba server on CentOS 7. I use this for general back up and resource sharing. I have noticed that transfer speeds over WiFi using ES File Explorer on my Android phone is incredibly slow, never going higher than 66Kbps.

1. Transferring files to/from the server using Ethernet runs at 10MBps, so pulling files from the server using a laptop connected to the home router runs at a normal 100Mbps.
2. Using my phone to download content from the internet is fast; I can stream YouTube in HD and download 20MB files fairly quickly.
3. Using my phone to download content shared by my laptop running Windows 10 runs at normal WiFi speeds, defined by 802.11b/g/n(this AP prefers 802.11n)

This question is floating around the internet, but I haven't seen any answer that can provide clarity on the situation or a solution to the problem. To provide more context to the question and situation, here are a few extra nibbles of information that may be important:

- https://www.tecmint.com/install-samba4-on-centos-7-for-file-sharing-on-windows/ -- The resource I used to create the samba server
- ntfs3g -- the software I used to mount my NTFS HDD on Centos7
- DLink DSL-2750U -- the home router I use as an access point
- Huawei Y560 -- the phone I use
- ES File Explorer 4.1.7.1.5 -- the version of ES File Explorer I use

[image: Wireless Network Settings Basic]

[image: Wireless Network Settings Advanced Complete]

Comment: Using a different Samba client(the client you suggested) gave me a download speed of over 1000Kbps. I will accept my phone as the root of the problem. If you've experienced this same problem with any protocol other than samba, please let me know. But I do accept your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this phone.

I got it through freedom Pop, I regret to inform you it's one of the worst I have ever owned. Try ANDsmb from the play store, just installing ex-file explorer on this phone made it run extremely sluggish.

Also, in your wireless settings you are on channel 4, channels 1, 6, & 11 are the non-overlapping channels for 2.4ghz wifi. I suspect you will get better throughput if you switch to one of those.

If you are using the 40mhz channel mode, you want the sideband as far away from the main band as possible.

Examples:

Main - ch1
Sideband - higher

Or,

Main- ch11
Sideband - lower

I also used a wifi widget to try and troubleshoot this speed issue. My phone would regularly fall back to slower Mbps rates when every other client was fine.

Note: because of the sluggishness, and what seemed like the processor freezing from time to time for 1-5 seconds, it made using csipsimple or any other sip client via WiFi unreliable.